# Terraform: Create an Azure policy (allowed location) - missing a value

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

I encountered the following error message, but I couldn't identify what I missed.

Error: creating Scoped Policy Assignment (Scope: "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Policy Assignment Name: "Allowed locations"): unexpected status 400 with error: PolicyParametersMissingValue: The policy parameters 'listOfAllowedLocations' are missing a value.

Below is my Terraform code.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  }

  terraform {
  required_providers {
      azurerm = {
          source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = ">= 2.96.0"
      }
  }
  }

  resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment" "Allowedlocations2" {
    name = "Allowed locations"
    subscription_id = var.cust_scope
    policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/e56962a6-4747-49cd-b67b-bf8b01975c4c"
    description = "This policy enables you to restrict the locations your organization can specify when deploying resources."
    display_name = "Allowed locations"
    metadata = <<METADATA
      {
      "category": "General"
      }
METADATA


    parameters = <<PARAMETERS
      {
          "listOfAllowedLocations": {
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
              "description": "The list of locations that can be specified when deploying resources.",
              "strongType": "location",
              "displayName": "Allowed locations",
              "strongType": "location"
            },
            "defaultValue": [
              "eastus"
            ],
            "allowedValues": [
              "eastus",
              "eastus2"
            ]
          }
        }
PARAMETERS

  }
```

As a Terraform beginner,  I've missed a value, but I'm unable to find it. If anyone knows what it is and how to find it, please let me know.

```
azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment.Allowedlocations2: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating Scoped Policy Assignment (Scope: "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Policy Assignment Name: "Allowed locations"): unexpected status 400 with error: **PolicyParametersMissingValue: The policy parameters 'listOfAllowedLocations' are missing a value.**
│
│   with azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment.Allowedlocations2,
│   on main.tf line 65, in resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment" "Allowedlocations2":
│   65:   resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment" "Allowedlocations2" {
│
│ creating Scoped Policy Assignment (Scope: "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Policy Assignment Name: "Allowed locations"): unexpected status 400 with error: PolicyParametersMissingValue: The policy parameters 'listOfAllowedLocations' are missing a value.
╵
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: creating Scoped Policy Assignment (Scope:
> "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" │ Policy Assignment Name: "Allowed locations"): unexpected status 400 with error: PolicyParametersMissingValue: The policy parameters
> 'listOfAllowedLocations' are missing a value.

The reason for the above error message indicates that the `listOfAllowedLocations` parameter is missing a value in your policy assignment.it seems you are defining the `parameters` block incorrectly.

When I try to pass it without the `listOfAllowedLocations` in the wrong format, I also get the same error as you.

[image]

Here is the update `Terraform code` to create Policy definition and assignment.

```json
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

data "azurerm_policy_definition" "example" {
  display_name = "Allowed locations"
}

output "id" {
  value = data.azurerm_policy_definition.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment" "example" {
  name                 = "Allowed Locations Policy-1"
  policy_definition_id = data.azurerm_policy_definition.example.id
  subscription_id      = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id

  parameters = jsonencode({
    listOfAllowedLocations = {
      value = ["eastus", "westus"]
    }
  })
}
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

Once ran the above code policy is assigned to `subscription` scope as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

But What I wanted is using the existing Azure policy (Built-in) without making new one.

Comment: Hi @uiiueree , I have updated my answer as per your requirement to assign **built-in Policy** using Terraform. Just pass the existing Built-in policy name in data block.
Kindly let me know, if you are facing any issue.